# Rails “Template is missing” error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am beginner in Rails.

In `routes.rb` I have

```
resources :posts
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9Xcj.png

when I click to "Add a new post" for the empty title of the post,I get a error like

```
Template is missing
Missing template posts/New, application/New with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}.
Searched in:
 * "/home/dilip/blog/app/views"
 * "/home/dilip/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/devise-3.0.0.rc/app/views"
```

Please Help!

Comment: Please show your `posts#create` action.

Comment: @MarekLipka                                                                       def create
  post = Post.new(params[:post])

  if post.save
   redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "your post was saved"
  else
   render "New"
  end
 end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

```
render "New"
```

in your controller. You should change it to:

```
render "new"
```

Answer (score 0):

That means that Rails is looking for `posts/new.html.erb`, and you don't have a `posts/new.html.erb` file. (Or haml file, or whatever templating language you're using.

Comment: I have posts/new.html.erb